# How i can get input value with php curl?

Tags: php, curl

İ want login instagram with php curl. When I try to login below code is always changing So i must get this input value:

```
<input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="uCbmYHcQLe18VAvVFXbfyPcS5kXtCuuE">
```

my curl code is:

```
<?php
    $url = "https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?force_classic_login";
    $values = "csrfmiddlewaretoken=" + $key + "&username=myusername&password=mypassword";
    $key = "";

    //foreach input name csrfmiddlewaretoken = $key

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $values);
    $veri = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    echo $veri;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$veri = curl_exec($curl);    // That $veri contains the curl response into it

$data = json_decode($veri, true);    // Convert the response into an array
```

now the `$data` is an array and you can access the values from this array by using its indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Man, explode the response content with the separator `<input` then get on array result your data.

Do something like this:

```
$result = explode('<input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="', $file_content);
$result = explode('">', $result[1] );
$input_value = $result[0];
$input_value = $result[0];
```

i hope this help

Comment: $result = explode('<input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="', $file_content);
    $result = explode('">', $result[1] );
    $input_value = $result[0];
    $input_value = $result[0];
    $key = $input_value;

Comment: i dont understand :(

Comment: Take your CURL result on `$file_content` variable and use the explode function for retrieve just value what you wanna ...